# Type cast doesn't call my user-defined conversion operator

Tags: c#, nunit

I have implemented a wrapper around the C# `long?` datatype, that corresponds to the SQL nullable datatype `BIGINT`, let's call the class `SqlBigInt`. I want it to be able to handle some cases of the C# standard `long` datatype as well as the nullable `long?`.

I am now implementing the `IComparable` interface in `SqlBigInt`. I have implemented an implicit user-defined conversion operator from `long` to `SqlBigInt`, but it doesn't seem to be called when I cast explicitly from my implementation of `CompareTo` (from the `IComparable` interface), at least when called from `NUnit`. I set a breakpoint in the conversion operator but it is not triggered.

This is my conversion operator:

```
public static implicit operator SqlBigInt(long integer)
{
    return new SqlBigInt(integer);
}
```

This works:

```
SqlBigInt bigInt = new SqlBigInt(1);
long longValue = 2;
bigint = longValue; // bigint is now 2.
```

But this casts an `InvalidCastException`:

```
public override int CompareTo(object other)
{
    try
    {
        SqlBigInt bigInt = (SqlBigInt)other;
        return CompareTo(bigInt);
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException exception)
    {
        // I end up here when I execute the code below.
        throw new ArgumentException(exception.Message);
    }
}
...
SqlBigInt bigInt = new SqlBigInt(3);
long longValue = 2;
Assert.That(bigInt, Is.GreaterThan(longValue));
```

Can implicit conversion operators not be called explicitly, or what am I missing here?

Comment: If you're implementing `IComparable<SqlBigInt>` then it should be `CompareTo(SqlBigInt other)`.

Comment: I am implementing that as well, and that is the method I'm calling after a successful cast. This is the implementation of the IComparable interface, without type specification.

Comment: You could fix it with `Assert.That(bigInt, Is.GreaterThan((SqlBigInt)longValue));`.  The issue is that the `long` is being boxed into an `object` and you didn't specify a `object` to `SqlBigInt` conversion.

Comment: Oh, I see! So if I implement a conversion operator from object to SqlBigInt (that checks if the object is a long) this would theoretically work? I'm not sure that that is desirable, just so I understand.

Comment: Yeah, you might want to change the non-generic `CompareTo` to attempt unboxing the long instead like `if(other is long l) return CompareTo((SqlBigInt)l);`

Comment: That is a good idea. If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Conversion operator work with explicit call :

```cs
SqlBigInt val = (SqlBigInt)15L;
```

But in your example, the code convert a object to SqlBigInt. No convertor exists to do this work :

```cs
object o = 15L;
SqlBigInt val = (SqlBigInt)o;
// throw System.InvalidCastException
```

A solution is to convert to long before to SqlBigInt like :

```cs
object o = 15L;
SqlBigInt val = (SqlBigInt)(long)o;
```